# Mysql база данных продукции

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята, пишу не большой сайт по продажи 4-5 видов продукции,возможно в дальнейшем увеличиться до 7 видов но не больше, ставить комбайны типа opencarta не вижу необходимости. Так вот в чем вопрос, создать одну таблицу со всеми видами и далее создать релятивные таблицы со свойствами (у некоторых товаров размеры фиксированные у других нет, некоторый товар шт некоторый в кг продается) или просто создать отдельную таблицу для каждого вида товара?!

Comment: С точки расширения кода лучше все однотипное вынести в одну таблицу, а различное разбить (подумать над динамикой). В вашем варианте, с вашей уверенностью, что не более 7 товаров - лепите разные таблицы и не будет мароки со связями и т.п.

Comment: Тоже больше к этому варианту склоняюсь, хотелось услышать совет от бывалых) Спасибо

Comment: Большая или не большая значения не имеет. товаров потенциально больше одного - все, делается таблица товаров. Основные свойства кладем в эту же таблицу, дополнительные в отдельную скорее всего в виде ключ-значение. А иначе вам ради 5 товаров придется писать 5 блоков кода. добавляете товар - добавляете блок кода и заодно пересматриваете весь остальной. В итоге на разработку и особенно на отладку потратите в 5 раз больше времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если рисовать [диаграмму объектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML#.D0.94.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.8A.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2) вашего приложения, то можно сразу выделить четыре сущности.

Абстрактно:

1. Товар
2. Склад (?)
3. Продажа
4. Покупатель (тут зависит от логики работы вашего приложения, может и не понадобится)

Соответственно теория(и практика) подсказывает, что каждой из этих сущностей потребуется отдельный(и единственный для каждого) справочник(он же таблица в БД)

Остановимся на "товаре", так как вопрос у вас по нему. У каждой единицы товара есть некоторые неотъемлемые атрибуты, как то: тип, наименование, единица продажи(штуки/килограмы), цена за единицу продажи, размеры/вес единицы продажи, etc. Все эти общие атрибуты имеет смысл хранить в справочнике(таблице) товаров.

Если же у некоторых типов товара существуют уникальные атрибуты, то для них потребуются отдельные справочники, связанные по ключу с записью в справочнике товаров.

А вот как организовать справочники уникальных атрибутов, будет это одна таблица типа "ключ"=>"значение", или несколько таблиц, заточенные под конкретные атрибуты - уже зависит от уникальности этих самых атрибутов и требований к ним.