# Оптимальное построение таблицы бд

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Доделываю свой интернет-магазин. Есть таблица `category` и `product`. Проблема в том, что к каждой категории товара идут разные свойства, к примеру, у категории плюшевых мишек нет длины стебля, а у цветов нет материала, из которого они изготовлены. Скажите, как правильно поступить в данной ситуации? В таблицу product добавлять столбцы с параметрами - будет очень широкая таблица, если будет много категорий, есть вариант создать таблицу свойств, которые будут привязаны к определенному товару, но опять же, правильно ли делать таким образом? Какое решение в этом случае оптимальное?

Comment: На мой взгляд, самое правильное - это добавить таблицу со списком свойств и таблицу, в которой будет храниться связь между категорией и свойством

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Mysql база данных продукции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645068/mysql-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Думаю, лучше не связь между категорией и свойством, а между продуктом и свойством.
То есть создать три таблицы category, product, properties. И ещё одну таблицу связь М:М между product и properties, где будут столбцы product_id, property_id, value. То есть здесь же можно сразу хранить значение по свойству для продукта.

Comment: Согласен со @Stargazer. Но, возможно таки лучше добавить связь между категориями и свойствами, чтобы при добавлении продукта эти свойства цеплялись к нему из категории, например, с какими-нибудь дефолтными или пустыми значениями. Иначе для каждого продукта нужно будет каждое свойство добавлять вручную. Таким образом получится следующее: Привязали свойства к категории, и при создании продукта в этой категории, свойства категории автоматически добавляются к нему.

Comment: Всем спасибо большое!